# Using nested functions

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I have problem: 
Write a function called minimum6 that takes 6 arguments and returns the smallest one. 
Example: minimum6 10 20 30 40 50 60 = 10

and this is what i got so far:

> let min a b = if a < b then a else b;;
>   let minimum6 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 = min (min (min (min (min x1 x2) x3) x4) x5) x6);;

however, i get 'This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type 'a -> 'b' pointing to the first '10'
I'm new to the language, what did i do wrong? was it because i used a function in a function?

Comment: You have some parentheses problems.

Comment: should i place parenthesis on all the values?

Comment: Correction-- I got it to work! darn brackets xD post it as an answer if you want the points!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some parentheses problems. :)

You could also do something more general.  Something like:

```
let rec list_min min = function
  | [] -> min
  | x::xs -> if x < min then list_min x xs else list_min min xs

let min6 x1 .. x6 = list_min x1 [x2; ...; x6]
```